# MongoDB - get message threads

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Messages collections:

```
{ "members": ["userA", "userB"], "content": "Some message" },
{ "members": ["userA", "userC"], "content": "Some message" },
{ "members": ["userA", "userB"], "content": "Some message 2" }
```

If I want to find message threads by `userA`, I expect this result: `["UserB", "UserC"]`

```
public function findUserThreads($user)
    {
        $data = $this->getCollection()->find(['members' => $user]);
        $threads = [];
        while($data->hasNext()){
            $msg = $data->getNext();
            if($msg['members'][0] != $user) {
                $threads[] = $msg['members'][0];
            }
            if($msg['members'][1] != $user) {
                $threads[] = $msg['members'][1];
            }
        }

        return array_values(array_unique($threads));
    }
```

I want to do this in mongodb, not in php.

Comment: what is expected output ? can you update your question ?

Comment: What do you mean by *group by user 1* what is your expected result? Please use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33132652/edit) to improve your question.

Comment: So you want to return array of all  users where `userA` is present. right?

Comment: Yes, I want to return array of all users where userA is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to this you need to use the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "members": "userA" }},
    { "$project": { 
        "users": { "$setDifference": [
            { "$map": { 
                "input": "$members", 
                "as": "m", 
                "in": { "$cond": [ 
                    { "$ne": [ "$$m", "userA" ] },
                    "$$m", 
                    false ]
                }
            }}, 
            [false]
        ]}
    }}, 
    { "$unwind": "$users" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null, 
        "users": { "$addToSet": "$users"}
    }}
])
```

Which returns:

```
{ "_id" : null, "users" : [ "userC", "userB" ] }
```